# Wordpress on local LAMP stack - How to allow PHP files to FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, ftp

No more cowboy coding! I'm trying to develop on my local machine, but I'm no Ubuntu expert!

I've got it to the point where when I browse to "localhost" in my browser, it pulls up my Wordpress install and runs the site. It's trying to update, and showing this prompt:

[image: Screenshot]

So it's trying to run FTP as what? I'm new to Ubuntu, on my shared Bluehost server space Wordpress has no trouble FTPing out. How do I configure this on my local Ubuntu machine so that Wordpress can update. It's a fresh Ubuntu install from ISO disk. Do I need to configure FTP somehow? This is probably a very basic question - I think I'm looking for a few shell commands as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in which you can disable the FTP Credentials for installing Plugins and Themes from backend

Just Add the following Code in wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```